# Why is $(window).resize() not firing or returning errors in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

This code works perfectly, except it skips over the entirety of the `$(window).resize` area. Removing all but one variable seems to 'fix it', but that's obviously not going to work.

Am I missing a glaringly obvious issue here? There are no errors in the console. Here's a demo if you want to pick at it or see the full javascript: http://jdsn.co/demo/reader.html

```
if( main_reader_height + offset_height > initviewport ) {
    $('.main_reader footer').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('.nav_items, .nav_prev, .nav_next').addClass('snap');
            $(window).resize(function() {
                window.offset = $('.main_reader article').offset().top;
                window.viewport = $(window).height();
                window.main_height = $('.main_reader article').height();
                window.bottom_offset = window.viewport - window.offset - window.main_height - 80
                $('.nav_next').height(viewport - offset - bottom_offset - 80);  
            });
            $('.snap').height(window.bottom_offset)
        }
        else {
            $('.nav_items, .nav_prev, .nav_next').removeClass('snap');
        }
    }, {
      offset: '100%'  // middle of the page
});
```

Comment: From looking at the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) it looks like the resize handler signature contains an event object parameter, so have you tried changing your JavaScript to `$(window).resize(function(e) {`?

Comment: @MarkM: If you're not using the parameter, you don't need to add it to the signature.  It will still be passed, but the function will ignore it (you can still access it via the `arguments` array).

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:

1. The .resize() event only gets subscribed to after the first callback from waypoint. In addtion, every time you get a waypoint event, you create a new subscriber to .resize(), which could lead to issues.
2. Any real reason you're using `window.` when defining those variables? That attaches them to the main window object, which really isn't needed, and might cause other issues.

From there, it depends on what you're expecting the behavior to be. Looking at the code doesn't quite convey what you're trying to accomplish. Further light on that may yield more helpful answers.